# Arguments passed to create a LogRecord in python

Tags: python, logging, python-internals

The `LogRecord` in python's [`logging module`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py) has a LogRecord defined as:

```
class LogRecord(object):
    """
    A LogRecord instance represents an event being logged.
    LogRecord instances are created every time something is logged. They
    contain all the information pertinent to the event being logged. The
    main information passed in is in msg and args, which are combined
    using str(msg) % args to create the message field of the record. The
    record also includes information such as when the record was created,
    the source line where the logging call was made, and any exception
    information to be logged.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, level, pathname, lineno,
                 msg, args, exc_info, func=None, sinfo=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize a logging record with interesting information.
        """
        ct = time.time()
        self.name = name
        self.msg = msg
        # more stuff below
```

This `LogRecord` gets created, for example whenever someone does a `logging` actions, such as:

```
def my_func():
    logging.info('Hello %s', 'Person')
    return 1
```

In the above logger call, the variables can be inferred as:

```
name = 'root' # using the root logger since calling `logging.`
level = 'INFO' # or, 20
msg = 'Hello %s'
args = ('Person',)
```

How does the introspection work to gather the other items from my `logging` call? For example:

- pathname
- lineno
- exc_info
- func
- sinfo # what is this?
- kwargs # is this just user-added kwargs, or something else?

For example, in your answer could you show an example of doing the introspection on a function call to gather the above information?

Comment: a debugger could answer it

Comment: @jfs -- would you want to show an example of how that could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all of it happens in [Logger.findCaller](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1502). It inspects the current frame for this information.

The kwargs argument of the default LogRecord constructor is not actually used. User supplied data is passed in through `extra`.

Comment: so it basically raises a fake `Exception` to get all the stack information from the logging call? That's quite interesting.

Comment: It does when sys._getframe is not available. If you are interested in what the object looks like that the information comes from you should see the traceback documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html